# Hover effect with transform: scale() affecting text elsewhere on page

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, transform

I have a some images links on my site whose hover effect is:

```
transform: scale(1.06,1.06);
```

In Chrome, during the scale effect, links elsewhere on the page (in the footer) appear to get thinner/lighter. After the effect is over, they go back to normal. Again, these links are not part of the element with the hover effect, they're just visible on the screen at the same time.

To fix this, I've tried:

```
transform: translateZ(0);  /* on the affected links in the footer */

transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* on the affected links in the footer */

transform: scale(1.06,1.06) transformZ(0) /* for the hover effect on the image */

backface-visibility: hidden /* on both the footer links and the image */

-webkit-font-smoothing: anti-aliased /* on the footer links */

will-change: transform; /* on the image, makes the footer links ALWAYS look thin */
```

Is there anything else I can try to fix this issue? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please put up a snippet which demonstrates the issue. I suspect it's to do with the whole page being redrawn because the size of the hovered element has changed so other stuff has had to change but I can't be sure without seeing your particular problem.

Comment: I originally created a fiddle, but the issue wasn't present, possibly because there was so much less on the page.

Comment: Do you have fixed dimensions on the page, or are you using flex or...

Comment: It's a flexbox layout, lots of rows and columns

Comment: Interestingly, it seems like it only happens for certain link colors in the footer. It's very obvious when I use red, but when I switch to white or lighter colors, it either doesn't happen or if it does, it's not noticeable.